# Identifying threads in embedded software design

Tags: multithreading, architecture, task, software-design

Even though the no of threads and its functionality solely depends on application, is there some generic tips or best practices available in deciding the number of threads and its functionality required for an embedded software application.

Any decision parameter suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for each of the data/event sources there will be one thread in charge of bringing data into the system. Any processing work that may take a longer time should be put into a thread. The core logic of the system should be in a thread too. In this design approach, a thread serves one of two purposes: to offload time consuming task so the core system will respond quickly and smoothly; and to encapsulate some component logic so the system can be partitioned properly.

There is also another view that says the number of threads should not exceed the number of processor cores. In this design view a thread usually is a general purpose processing unit in a pool. A data input or event would be passed to any idle thread from the pool to be handled. After processing an event, the thread will go back to the pool and be ready to take the next event. This approach is typically used by the data-processing/information-technology/enterprise software. In this design a thread does not serve as a logic encapsulation tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think "There is also another view that says the number of threads should not exceed the number of processor cores." is correct as we are discussing about multithread programming and not multicore programming